# what should be value of $f(x)$ to make $f(x)$ continuous at $x = 0$ where $f(x) = (\cos x)^{(1/x)}$

Tags: limits, continuity

This was a problem asked to me in an interview. i am not sure about the continuity as on one side of 0 the function reaches 0 and on the other it tends to infinity. so can it be continuous?

Comment: Was this an interview in the industry?

Answer (score 1):

Near $x=0$ we have $\cos x>0$ and hence $$\ln f(x)=\frac1x\ln\cos x. $$
Also, $\cos x\approx 1-\frac12x^2$ so $\ln\cos x\approx -\frac12x^2$, $\ln f(x)\approx \frac x2$ and clearly $\ln f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. Hence $f(x)\to 1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering Hagen. I applied the general e^((1/g)(1-f)) for general 1^infinity(f^g) type of questions and was able to come to 1 as solution, but (cos0 - δ)^(infinity) tends to 0 whereas (cos0 - δ)^(-infinity) tends to infinity. so can you cite any other example in which limit exists but are approaching to a different value on both sides of computation point?